# Gradient Background color in Java

Tags: android, gradient

I am working on android Project, I was using Gradient Background that I link to drawable but in one case I have background from Java Main Activity. I want to use same Background there too.

This is code I use in XML layout.

```
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:centerColor="#16a085"
    android:endColor="#2980b9"
    android:startColor="#2980b9" />
```

I want to work in java with same gradient which is now like the screenshot below and its single color.
[How Can I Use Gradient in this place ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwsMl.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the Gradient as an XML in your drawable.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
android:angle="135"
android:centerColor="#16a085"
android:endColor="#2980b9"
android:startColor="#2980b9" />
</shape>
```

Replace

```
 ab.setBackgroundDrawable (new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(#2c3e50')));
```

with

```
ab.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.color_gradient);
```